# Browserify Import from URL not working

Tags: javascript, browserify

I'm using Browserify trying to import a module (jquery) from a URL, but it's not working:

```
import $ from 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'
```

throws error:

```
> browserify wwwroot/js/index.js -t babelify --outfile wwwroot/js/bundle.js

Error: Cannot find module 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js' from 'C:\Dev\Sample\Sample.Web\wwwroot\js'
    at C:\Dev\Sample\Sample.Web\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:46:17
    at process (C:\Dev\Sample\Sample.Web\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:173:43)
    at ondir (C:\Dev\Sample\Sample.Web\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:188:17)
    at load (C:\Dev\Sample\Sample.Web\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:69:43)
    at onex (C:\Dev\Sample\Sample.Web\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:92:31)
    at C:\Dev\Sample\Sample.Web\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:22:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

Is this supported?

Comment: I removed the ecmascript-6 tag since it has nothing to do with ES6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this supported?

No it is not. However, there is a plugin that allows to load libraries from jsDelivr, a CDN: https://github.com/dsdenes/browserify-cdnjs